# MongoDB - query array of objects contains specific values

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am building a simple recipe app for practice, and I have a collection containing all the recipes with its ingredients:

```json
{
        "_id": "640a5f1fa99f441f56e0996c",
        "schema": 0,
        "userId": "640a46b8b9447ba3c4832c3d",
        "name": "banana smoothie",
        "ingredients": [
            {
                "name": "banana",
                "qty": 2,
                "unit": "unit"
            },
            {
                "name": "milk",
                "qty": 1,
                "unit": "cup"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Now I'm trying to build a query that will allow me to find all the recipes I can make with the ingredients I have.

For example:

1. If I have just bananas, I can't make the Banana Smoothie (missing milk)
2. If I have bananas, milk, and apples, the query should return the Banana Smoothie

So far, I have something like this:

```
find({'ingredients.name': {$all:['banana', 'milk']}, ingredients: {$size:2}})
```

This would find all the recipes with banana AND milk, and nothing else, but would fail for case 2 of my example.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You are looking for something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/B8lKaRzJJoy)?

Comment: Did you consider using [`$and:`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/and/)

Comment: Yes! I think that works @ray, thank you so much. If you add it as an answer I'll mark it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using `$all`, you are requiring the array `ingredients.name` to contain all values of `['banana', 'milk', 'apple']`. So for your case, you should use `$setIsSubset`

```js
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $and: [
      {
        "$setIsSubset": [
          "$ingredients.name",
          [
            "banana",
            "milk",
            "apple"
          ]
        ]
      },
      {
        $eq: [
          {
            $size: "$ingredients"
          },
          2
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/B8lKaRzJJoy)